# jQuery hover slide up but show first list item always

Tags: jquery, css

I've been mucking around with this jsfiddle code but can't get it to do what I want, in fact I don't think it's possible the way I've done it so would be open to new suggestions.

http://jsfiddle.net/GwBuj/118/

On Hover I want the list of items to slide up, which it does, but I would like it to always show the first list item just above the button before hover, then on hover slide up the rest of the list. But because it's using display:none I can't figure out a way to allow it to show the first list item.

Comment: thy this http://jsfiddle.net/GwBuj/121/, is this ur requirement??

Comment: Here is a way to do this. I just change a little the structure in the div. http://jsfiddle.net/GwBuj/123/ ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had a quick go, is this along the right lines of what you want to do? http://jsfiddle.net/cUFNR/

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to try, but I noticed your mouseover/mouseout does a freakout when the menu is hovered over, so I tweaked your code a bit:  http://jsfiddle.net/cUFNR/1/

Comment: Yeah pretty much, animate seems the right way to go, is there a way to stop it looping when hovered back and forth? A return false or something?

Comment: @Yammi No prob.  @Kobius Yours was the same problem I ran into a while back that I struggled with until someone showed me the two parameter hover :P  Never gonna forget that.

Answer (score 0):

Just only for having a better behaviour, use stop() to avoid unwanted effects when multiple hovering:

http://jsfiddle.net/cUFNR/2/

```
  $('.button').hover(
    function() {
        $(".slide").stop().animate({height:'100px'}, 500);
    }, function() {
        $(".slide").stop().animate({height:'20px'}, 500);
    });
```